# Creating javascript var dynamically not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create javascript variable dynamically.

```
var id = "_wuserId"
```

I need to create a variable

```
var _wuserId_editor = new Editor();
```

I have tried

```
var eval(id + "_editor") = new Editor();
```

Above code doesnt work

I am not quite sure how to use associative array, I have tried following but it didnt work.

```
var editor_id = ["_wuserId_editor"];

var editor_id[0] = new Editor();
```

Please help

Comment: Usually, the way to solve this type of issue is to not use named variables, but to either put your values into an array or make them named properties of an object both of which can be manipulated at runtime quite easily.

Comment: I think it will be easier to use those dynamic names as object key than as variables

Comment: I have updated code to reflect what I have tried

Answer (score 1):

You can't... but you can build an object to stores them (it looks like an associative array when you use it)

`var varx['the_id']="whatever"`

Answer (score 0):

Since global variables are part of the `window` object, just access them via

```
window["x_" + string]
```

Or put them in an own associative array.

The same works with other objects, and also with `this`. Get creative!

```
var a = {};
a.foobar = 42;
a.foo = function() {
    var s = "bar";
    alert(this['foo' + s]); // prints 42
}
```

Another way would be to use `eval`

```
var b = eval("x_" + string);
```

But be aware of `eval`'s dangers: [When is JavaScript's eval() not evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil)

Comment: Interesting... Should be considered (or in fact they are) variables properties of the "window object"?